# How can I enumerate files from Files app without using "UIDocumentPickerViewController"?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I want to access all files from "**On my iPhone**" tab from "**Files App**".
 Currently, I'm using **UIDocumentPickerViewController** to select/pick files. I don't want to present any picker to get files same as we use **[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:options:]** to get the photos from **Photos App**.

or can I use NSFileProviderManager to achieve this?
Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

By definition files from **On My Phone tab** are located outside your app sandbox and as far as i know you cannot go and walk outside your app sandbox (or app groups).

> *UIDocumentPickerViewController* is a view controller that provides access to documents or destinations outside your app’s sandbox. Ok but thought their private APIs

maybe you´re missing something or you should rethink your app behaviour.

On the other hand PHAsset is a class that grant access to Photo Library that every app can access or modify but **requires explicit authorization** from the user.

So Apple is very clear in the ecosystem of apps, please refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) page for more information.

Hope it help clarify your mind.

Comment: Thanks, @blek!! I know that we can't access anything outside our app's sandbox but still, I want to confirm that if similar to PHAsset/Photos is there any framework or APIs to access files from Files app. I'm clear about UIDocumentPickerViewController and UIDocumentBrowserViewController, no doubts about it.

Comment: go through these documents by Apple to access the documents outside your app's sandbox.
<br><br>
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451-CH2-SW3

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/2902364-documentpicker?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: The meaning of the provided URLs varies depending on the document picker’s mode:

UIDocumentPickerModeImport

The URLs refer to a copy of the selected documents. These documents are temporary files. They remain available only until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, move these files to a permanent location inside your sandbox.

UIDocumentPickerModeOpen

The URLs refer to the selected documents. The provided URLs are security-scoped, referring to files outside your app’s sandbox. For more about working with external, security-scoped URLs, see Requirements.